# GNU make variables in Makefile

Tags: variables, makefile

I would like to create a Makefile which also creates a simple script for running the compiled application.

I have something like the following:

```
@touch $(SCRIPT)
@echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(LIB_DIR) $(APP_DIR)/$(APP) $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 > $(SCRIPT)
@chmod +x $(SCRIPT)
@echo Script successfully created.
```

And I want $1 $2 ... to appear in the script exactly like $1 $2 ... to represent scripts command-line arguments. I can't get it worked because Makefile is using $1 $2 as its own variables.. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use double dollar sign to tell make you mean a literal `$`, not a variable expansion, and single-quote the whole thing to prevent further shell expansion when echoed:

```
@echo 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(LIB_DIR) $(APP_DIR)/$(APP) $$1 $$2 $$3 $$4 $$5 $$6'
```

Comment: and a I would like to prepend the LD_LIBRA... line with the #!/bin/bash line but after @echo '#!/bin/bash' no line appears in the script. What could be the problem this time?

Comment: you are a life saver. Thanks. The trick was a to use `\$$i` in my case. where 'i' was a variable in my loop.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the `$` by doubling it:

```
@echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(LIB_DIR) $(APP_DIR)/$(APP) $$1 $$2 $$3 $$4 $$5 $$6 > $(SCRIPT)
```

If you’ve got secondary expansion activated (don’t worry – you probably haven’t!) you need to double the `$`s again, resulting in e.g. `$$$$1`.

By the way, the `@touch` command is redundant.

Comment: I think that the echo is run in a subshell (especially because there's an output redirect) so the shell also expands the variables. Quote it like in my answer and it works for me.